# Simple database lookup - keeps looping

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code running on my website.  I call it from a html form.  The form has a client number which looks up the redirect value in the database and should redirect to the website.  The redirect works great with one value in the database.  However, when I add more values it uses the last one.  I added the echo goto so I can see.  The script pulls every redirect value for the whole database.  How can I just pull the redirect value associated with the client_number?

```
<php 

$host="localhost"; // Host name  
$username=""; // Mysql username  
$password=""; // Mysql password  
$db_name=""; // Database name  
$tbl_name="clients"; // Table name  

// Connect to server and select databse. 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 

// sent from form
$myclient=$_POST['myclient']; 

$myclient = stripslashes($myclient); 

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE client_number='$myclient'"; 

$result=mysql_query($sql); 


$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

if($count==1){ 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT redirect FROM clients"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 


$goto = $row['redirect'];
//added to see output
echo $goto; 
//header ("location: $goto");
} 
exit(); 
} 
else { 
echo "Account number is invalid"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: [Use of this extension (mysql_query) is discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query you are pulling all redirect

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT redirect FROM clients");
```

which should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT redirect FROM clients WHERE clientID=1234");
```

Then you were using `while` instead of `if`

```
if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { }
```

Using `header('Location: xyz.ext')` redirect in loop is bad

Comment: Thank you.  I made the couple of changes and it is working great.

Comment: [Use of this extension (mysql_query) is discouraged](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)